# How to calculate a transformed conic curve?

Tags: conic-sections

The origin question came from I want to move from A to B with a conic curve, and its model was like this:

Say We have a curve transformed from $y=x^2$ (just with rotation and movement)

[image]

And is there a transform that could let me calculate the samples of the curve?

in another word I want samples serial to be like this `[(5.5,-0.5), ... (1,2)]`

Comment: I think the best idea would be to use a parametric form for the curve. Then you can easily rotate it in the plane.

Comment: @MattiP. it's no linear-transformation? right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a parametric form of the curve:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x &=& t \\
y &=& t^2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
When $t$ gets some range, it plots the usual graph of $y= x^2$. Now we must rotate it about the $z$-axis, with some angle $\theta$:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{\text{rotated}} \\ y_{\text{rotated}}
\end{array}
\right]
= 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x \\ y
\end{array}
\right]
= 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\cos{\theta} t - \sin{\theta}t^2 \\ \sin{\theta}t + \cos{\theta}t^2
\end{array}
\right]
$$
So if you choose $\theta$, this set of points represents the rotated curve. The only thing left is to displace the curve by a desired amount, let's say
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{\text{final}} \\ y_{\text{final}}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{\text{rotated}} \\ y_{\text{rotated}}
\end{array}
\right]
+\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{\text{displacement}} \\ y_{\text{displacement}}
\end{array}
\right]
= 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\cos{\theta} t - \sin{\theta}t^2 + x_{\text{displacement}} \\ \sin{\theta}t + \cos{\theta}t^2 + y_{\text{displacement}}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
And we're done.

Comment: thanks, I write code according to the equation you give and it works

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you are asking, that you want to rotate and translate a parabola, one way to do it is to use a rotation matrix. You can consider the coordinates $(x, y) $ as the vectors $ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2 $, and the linear transformation in the standard ordered bases of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ given by $ r_\theta : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}  $. You can then move it around. I think the rest immediately follows.